# How are different styles and weights of web fonts rendered?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is a general question about why certain font weights and styles need to be specifically included, but not others.

I use Open Sans and Roboto Mono web fonts on my website, hosted on Google fonts, with the basic `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto+Mono" rel="stylesheet">` statement in the HTML head. As one would expect, I don't have to specify that I want bold font weight or italic style  text in the `<link>`; all browsers can generally handle `<foo style="font-weight: bold">` and `<foo style="font-style: italic">` and render those stylistic changes, even though it's technically a separate font (of the same typeface) that I haven't included.

However, if I wanted `<foo style="font-weight: lighter">` (or `<foo style="font-weight: 200">`) and `<foo style="font-style: oblique">`, it won't render: `lighter` just looks like `normal`, and `oblique` looks like `italic`.

I know how to make it work, obviously; I'm just wondering two things:

- How does the browser "make" the bold and italic (and bold-italic) versions of a typeface without the font?
- Why can't it "make" the lighter and oblique versions?

*NB: Typeface refers to the set of typographical symbols and characters in a particular shape (eg: Open Sans or Roboto Mono), and font is the typeface in a specific style (eg: Open Sans 400 italic or Roboto Mono 200 Italic)*

Answer (score 2):

You can find user friendly explanations to your question on the [`font-weight` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight), including:

- [Meaning of relative weights](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Meaning_of_relative_weights)

```
   Base element    Bolder      Lighter
-----------------------------------------
        100         400         100
        200         400         100
        300         400         100
        400         700         100
        500         700         100
        600         900         400
        700         900         400
        800         900         700
        900         900         700
```

- [Common font weight mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#Common_weight_name_mapping).

A more technical set of documentation can be found in official specs.
The current Candidate Recommendation CSS Fonts Module is [Fonts Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-fonts-3/#font-weight-prop) which is unchanged from the counterpart definition in Fonts Module Level 1.

In CSS Font Module Level 4 (currently working draft) there are a few notable changes proposed:

- font-weight numeric values will vary from `1` to `1000`
- there might be additional strings mapped to particular numeric values (i.e: `thin` => `100`, `medium` => `500`, etc).

Browsers currently display the closest available font weight to `400` for `font-weight: normal` and the closest available font weight to `700` for `font-weight: bold`.

To make sure a particular font-weight is used, you need to:

- load the weight
- specify the exact numeric weight for your element(s).

---

To load multiple font weights from font files, use multiple `@font-face` declarations:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont-normal.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('myfont-normal.woff') format('woff'),
     url('myfont-normal.ttf') format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('myfont-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('myfont-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('myfont-italic.woff') format('woff'),
     url('myfont-italic.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont-bold-italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('myfont-bold-italic.woff') format('woff'),
     url('myfont-bold-italic.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

In the above example, the file names don't really matter. What matters is that they point to the file containing the correct font style and font weight glyphs.

---

For Google fonts, it's easier. When loading more than just the default weight, specify all weights and styles as comma separate values, after the font-family name followed by a colon:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=MyFamily:n,i,b,bi" rel="stylesheet">
```

Besides `n` (`normal`), `bi` (`bolditalic`), you can also load numeric values: `400`, `400i`.

To find out more on how to load multiple weights, styles and subsets of the same font family from Google, you should read their ["Getting started"](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) page.

Note the required font styles, weights and subsets **need to be available** in order to be usable. If you request something that does not exist, Google will return the closest match to your request from available weights/styles/subsets.
You can easily see a list of available weights, styles and subsets on each font page and the correct URL will be generated for you by checking the appropriate checkboxes.